# Query to get count of Rows within a date range stored in records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the number of records that have the same FKID and are in the same range of Dates (between Start and End)
For Example:
FK ID has 2 rows that are within the given date range: ID 210 is between 10:15-11:32 and ID 213 is between 10:30 and 11:47 (they are also on the same day). I need a query that will tell me which IDs have the same FKID and are within the same range. I've been working at this for a while but can't figure it out! Thanks!

| ID | FKID | Start | End | TotalTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 208 | 40 | 2021-07-29 09:30:00.000 | 2021-07-29 09:30:00.000 | 0.9 |
| 209 | 37 | 2021-07-29 10:00:00.000 | 2021-07-29 10:00:00.000 | 0.9 |
| 210 | 39 | 2021-07-29 10:15:00.000 | 2021-07-29 11:32:00.000 | 77.76 |
| 211 | 40 | 2021-07-29 13:00:00.000 | 2021-07-29 14:17:00.000 | 77.76 |
| 212 | 34 | 2021-07-29 13:00:00.000 | 2021-07-29 14:28:00.000 | 88.8685714285714 |
| 213 | 39 | 2021-07-29 10:30:00.000 | 2021-07-29 11:47:00.000 | 77.76 |

Comment: upvoted just for getting the table format right on your first question, rather than using images.

Answer (score 3):

We first need to do a self join to get all the rows in the table with the Same `FKID`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    T AS t1
        INNER JOIN T AS t2
            ON t2.FKID = t1.FKID -- SAME FKID
            AND t2.ID <> t1.ID -- Different ID;
```

The condition `t2.ID <> t1.ID` will ensure you aren't joining the same row to itself, instead looking for other rows in the same table. This will return all combinations of rows, e.g.

| ID1 | ID2 |
| --- | --- |
| 210 | 213 |
| 213 | 210 |

If however you only want each tuple once, you can change to `t2 > t1.ID` which will return only

| ID1 | ID2 |
| --- | --- |
| 210 | 213 |

Then for overlapping ranges, the verbose version of the logic is:

- Start date of 2nd Row is after Start of first row and before and end date of 1st Row **OR**
- End date of 2nd Row is after Start of 1st Row and before the end date of 1st Row

So in SQL terms this becomes:

```
CREATE TABLE #T (ID INT, FKID INT, Start DATETIME, [End] DATETIME, TotalTime INT);

INSERT INTO #T(ID, FKID, Start, [End], TotalTime)
VALUES
    (208, 40, '2021-07-29 09:30:00', '2021-07-29 09:30:00', 0.9),
    (209, 37, '2021-07-29 10:00:00', '2021-07-29 10:00:00', 0.9),
    (210, 39, '2021-07-29 10:15:00', '2021-07-29 11:32:00', 77.76),
    (211, 40, '2021-07-29 13:00:00', '2021-07-29 14:17:00', 77.76),
    (212, 34, '2021-07-29 13:00:00', '2021-07-29 14:28:00', 88.8685714285714),
    (213, 39, '2021-07-29 10:30:00', '2021-07-29 11:47:00', 77.76);

SELECT  t1.*
FROM    #T AS t1
        INNER JOIN #T AS t2
            ON t2.FKID = t1.FKID -- SAME FKID
            AND t2.ID <> t1.ID -- Different ID 
WHERE   (t2.Start > t1.Start AND t2.Start < t1.[End])
OR      (t2.[End] > t1.Start AND t2.[End] < t1.[End]);
```

We can however simplify this with [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to simply:

```
SELECT  t1.*
FROM    #T AS t1
        INNER JOIN #T AS t2
            ON t2.FKID = t1.FKID -- SAME FKID
            AND t2.ID <> t1.ID -- Different ID
WHERE   t2.Start < t1.[End]
AND     t2.[End] > t1.Start;
```

In both cases the output is:

| ID | FKID | Start | End | TotalTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 210 | 39 | 2021-07-29 10:15:00.000 | 2021-07-29 11:32:00.000 | 77.76 |
| 213 | 39 | 2021-07-29 10:30:00.000 | 2021-07-29 11:47:00.000 | 77.76 |

**[Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=575b854f6b3756125f715cdf3a0bfc4a)**

---

If you want to include rows where the start date equals the end date of a previous row, then just change `<` to `<=` and `>` to `>=`:

```
SELECT  t1.*
FROM    #T AS t1
        INNER JOIN #T AS t2
            ON t2.FKID = t1.FKID -- SAME FKID
            AND t2.ID <> t1.ID -- Different ID
WHERE   t2.Start <= t1.[End]
AND     t2.[End] >= t1.Start;
```

**[Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bf262f5922d4f7ceb6ed7f819dded9c9)** <sup>*note rows with ID 214 and 215*</sup>

Comment: The only line i removed was "AND t2.ID <> t1.ID -- Different ID" and this worked for me =)

Comment: I actually just realized that this does not take into consideration when the times start at the same time. I thought it was a simple change, but is not. Investigating and will share the details, but if you know how, please share =)

Comment: Should just be a case of changing `>` to `>=` and `<` to `<=`. I've added a couple of extra rows in [this db<>fiddle](*https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bf262f5922d4f7ceb6ed7f819dded9c9) (IDs 214, and 215 where 215 starts at the same time 214 ends) and with the change they are also returned

Comment: I had a typo. This did it! =) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can JOIN the table with itself, looking for records of the same FKID whose ranges overlap (StartA <= EndB) and (EndA >= StartB)

This returns the overlaping IDs :

```
select A.ID as ID1, B.ID as ID2
from MyTable as A
     inner join MyTable as B on A.FKID = B.FKID and 
                                A.Start <= B.End and 
                                A.End >= B.Start
```

While this query just returns the number of overlaping rows.

```
select count(*) as Overlaps
from MyTable as A
     inner join MyTable as B on A.FKID = B.FKID and 
                                A.Start <= B.End and 
                                A.End >= B.Start
```